# Warning: a string ref, 'code', has been found within a strict mode tree. String refs are a source of potential bugs and should be avoided

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to put some code snippet in the page using `react-highlight`, following its documentation I wrote the following code:

```js
<Highlight className='javascript'>
{
    <div children={`import React from 'react';
import './Hello.scss';
const Hello = () => {
return (
<>
<div>
Hello world!
</div>
</>
)
}
export default Hello;`}/>

}
</Highlight>
```

it worked well and provided syntax highlighting. However, I got the following console warning:

```
Warning: A string ref, "code", has been found within a strict mode tree. String refs are a source of potential bugs and should be avoided. We recommend using useRef() or createRef() instead. 
    in pre (created by Highlight)
    in Highlight (created by Learning)
    in details (created by Learning)
    in div (created by Learning)
    in div (created by Learning)
    in Learning (created by Layout)
    in Route (created by Layout)
    in Switch (created by Layout)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (created by Layout)
    in Layout
    in StrictMode
```

My understanding is this is a warning caused by `react-highlight`, is there anything I can do to remove it?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I've never heard of the package but it appears it hasn't been [updated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight) in 3 years - which is a very good reason not to use it.

Comment: If you really want the warning to just not show up then of course you could simply not use StrictMode...

Comment: @RobinZigmond yeah good point, it works here without warning though? https://codesandbox.io/s/5kz6kyprxp

Comment: that's because the sandbox isn't using `React.StrictMode` anywhere - whereas clearly (from the console warning) your application is.

Comment: Is there a way I could remove the warning without disabling the Strict mode?

Comment: [I don't think so](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-legacy-string-ref-api-usage)

Comment: Can you provide an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: well I don't have an answer - I'm not sure either "don't use such an old package" or "turn Strict Mode off" really count. Happy to have helped though, if I did.